# why list can't be initialized with array, without arrays.aslist()?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

`Arrays.asList()` is declared as below.

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

So, as you know, to initialise a concrete `List` with an array, you can do this:

```java
String[] strings = new String[] {"hello", "world"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strings));
```

But what about this?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(new String[]{"hello", "world"});
```

I expected it would works, but didn't.

I understand why. It's because one of the constructors of `ArrayList` demands `Collection` class.

Then, what about `Arrays.asList()` ?

Varargs are compiled as array, so maybe that method would be compiled as below.

```java
public static <T> List<T> asList(T[] a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

But it actually returns `ArrayList` object. Why is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, `Arrays.asList` [is implemented as you said](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L2827), but `ArrayList` doesn't actually refer to the [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) that we all know and love. It refers to a private inner class in the `Arrays` class. From the first link, just under the declaration of `asList`, you will see:

```
/**
 * @serial include
 */
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
{
    ...
```

`new ArrayList<>(a)` is referring to the above class. The above class has a constructor that takes an `E[]`:

```
    ArrayList(E[] array) {
        if (array==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        a = array;
    }
```

But the `java.util.ArrayList` class doesn't have such a constructor, so it is no wonder that you can't do:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(new String[]{"hello", "world"});
```

Another big difference between `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is that you can add/remove elements to the former, but you can't to the latter. e.g. This throws an exception:

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").add("d");
```

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely never understood why such a constructor does not exist in `java.util.ArrayList` to begin with and the decision to name an inner class `ArrayList` too - is even more interesting. So you are simply looking in the wrong place, nothing more.

They *did* add such a construct (!= `constructor`), but only in java-9 and only to immutable collections:

```
List<String> list = List.of(new String[]{"one"});
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but that's not a constructor, but a factory method. A pretty pointless one, considering there already is one exactly like it - namely `Arrays.asList() `.

Comment: @daniu Note that `Arrays.asList()` is modifiable - and set/replaceAll affects the content of the original array whereas `List.of` content is a not modifiable copy of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList() is read only collection.

To new ArrayList(...) you have to pass a collection as an argument.

A collection in java is a List, Set